# How to search in git (in all of previous file)? Is this possible?

Tags: git

Well, I have a big problem. My developer mate didn't fill in the commit messages in the right way. So I don't know which is the right commit.

However! I know that it contains a special text, somewhere in the project. (I do not know the exactly file - although I have a suspect folder (src/) ).

This project has a lot of commit (just without commit message).

How to search string in every file that has ever existed?

Comment: Short answer is `git log -S"something"` (or even `git log -S"something" -- path/to/suspect/folder` to only search in a specific folder) but there must be a duplicate around here.

Comment: `[git] search files for string` leads to numerous results, the first one being the suggested duplicate (which itself is closed as a duplicate, but I find the first answer to this one clearer). Searching StackOverflow can't be that difficult?